# What is the best way to check the equality of a etree._Element and a bs4.Tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I use lxml to execute xpath to get a node of the type etree._Element.
I also have some node of the type bs4.Tag.

Then I want to know if these two nodes are referring to the same HTML element. What's the best way to do this?

What I currently do is a very simple way that I check the equality of the following things (such as) :

1. tag name
2. HTML attributes such as id, class, etc
3. string content
   ...

or just simply the canonical path from the root to that node.

However, this is not convenient.

Comment: None of these will help you decide if they refert to the same HTML element. You will have to compare the paths that led you to them.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank sure....

Comment: Why not just pick a library and stick with it?

Comment: @pguardiario I want to use the covenant functions provide by bs4 to deal with DOM tree, but it cannot execute xpath.

Comment: Covenant functions? I think you made that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can help you to compare path up to `html` element, taking into account tags and attributes, but comparing element's text is quite tricky

```
def compare_elements(bs_tag, lxml_element):
    # running till the very top
    while bs_tag.name != 'html' and lxml_element.tag != 'html':
        # compare tag
        if bs_tag.name != lxml_element.tag:
            return False

        # compare attributes
        # bs groups into lists, so we need to join back to string
        bs_attrs = {k: ' '.join(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v for k, v in bs_tag.attrs.items()}
        if bs_attrs != lxml_element.attrib:
            return False

        # going up
        bs_tag = bs_tag.parent
        lxml_element = lxml_element.getparent()

    return True
```